# CouchDB save doc uri incorrect

Tags: post, couchdb, cloudant

I am really scratching my head over this one. I am using cloudant as my couchdb provider and attempting to save a document to my db. I first establish what my db is in the following code.

db = jQuery.couch.db("https://fullscore.cloudant.com/fullscore");

I do a console.log and see that the URI and name are correct in the object.

```
db.saveDoc(doc, {
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("posted");
                },
                error: function(status) {
                    console.log("failure");
                }
            });
```

However when I look at the post, it posts to: https://cloudant.com/https%3A%2F%2Ffullscore.cloudant.com%2Ffullscore/

Which as you can see is totally wrong. Obviously there is something built in to append onto cloudant.com ... anyone know how this can be overridden?  Or perhaps its some other problem? I'm getting a 404 error.

--Ashley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the exact code, you need to set the URL prefix on your couch object, then use just the db name:

```
$.couch.urlPrefix = "https://username.cloudant.com";
var db = $.couch.db("dbname");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're passing the full database URL in a place where you're only supposed to pass the database name (i.e. the latter "fullscore" part in https://fullscore.cloudant.com/fullscore"). You've probably already set up the host name at some earlier point in your program.